# JavaScript function openFullscreen() , how to get it worked for several iframes on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, each

On page I have an iframe with *.pdf file in src.

```html
<div class="node--view-mode-full">

<p><iframe allow="fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="980" scrolling="no" src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" width="660"></iframe></p>

<p><iframe allow="fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="980" scrolling="no" src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" width="660"></iframe></p>

</div>
```

The build-in pdf-viewers in browsers now do not support fullscreen mode in iframes.

I found the solution https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp, that resolves the problem - open the iframe in fullscreen mode. In example from w3schools the button, that opens the iframe, already exists in HTML https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_fullscreen.

In my solution, I add button via JavaScript, because pages with iframes already exist without such buttons:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(".node--view-mode-full iframe[src*='.pdf']").each(function (index) {
        $(this).addClass('fullscreenframe');
        $(this).attr('id', 'fullscreen-'+index);
        $('<button onclick="openFullscreen()">Open in Fullscreen Mode</button>&nbsp;<strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.<br>').insertBefore(this);
    });

});
```

and after that add a function that opens iframe on fullscreen (same as on w3schools):

```
function openFullscreen() {
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreenframe")[0];
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
};
```

Everything working fine when I have only one iframe with *.pdf on the page. But when I have two or more iframes on the page, and I clicking on a any button "Open in Fullscreen Mode" near any iframe, I always see only first *.pdf on fullsceen mode...

I know, that it happens because I get only first iframe in `elem = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreenframe")[0];`

I know that I need to use each or something like that, but I can't to resolve it. In search all solutions about one fullscreen element on the page and there is no solution about multiple elements on the page.

Comment: Your function has to loop through all the elements returned by `getElementsByClassName()`. It can do that with a simple `for` loop or with `.forEach()`.

Comment: You might consider a `title="something"` for readers who need assistive technology ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#accessibility_concerns That way those readers get an assist with the PDF

Comment: Also do you really need `$(this).attr('id', 'fullscreen-'+index);` OR perhaps put that in the markup depending on the rendering in use there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(".node--view-mode-full iframe[src*='.pdf']").each(function (index) {
        $(this).addClass('fullscreenframe');
        $(this).attr('id', 'fullscreen-'+index);
        $('<button onclick="openFullscreen(' + index + ')">Open in Fullscreen Mode</button>&nbsp;<strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.<br>').insertBefore(this);
    });

});


function openFullscreen(index) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreenframe")[index];
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to get the list of elements every time you click. Also jQuery can delegate the click so your solution is not super elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Why not consolidate on jQuery?

Note the snippet below is not allowed to run in Stack Overflow

Also I changed the invalid P to a div with a class as suggested in a comment

This one will run https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/0v1kamyf/ but still give error due to security

```js
const fullScreen = elem => elem.requestFullscreen && elem.requestFullscreen(); // all modern browsers including Safari

$(function() {
  $(".node--view-mode-full iframe[src*='.pdf']").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('fullscreenframe');
    $(this).attr('id', 'fullscreen-' + index);
    $('<button class="fullScreen">Open in Fullscreen Mode</button>&nbsp;<strong>Tip:</strong> Press the "Esc" key to exit full screen.<br>').insertBefore(this);
  });
  $(".fullScreen").on("click", function() {
    const $iFrame = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('iframe.fullscreenframe');
    if ($iFrame) fullScreen($iFrame.get(0)); // pass the DOM element
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="node--view-mode-full">
  <div class="wrapper"><iframe allow="fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="980" scrolling="no" src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" width="660"></iframe></div>
  <div class="wrapper"><iframe allow="fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="980" scrolling="no" src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" width="660"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this as a better solution and is pretty much what I was going to post also.  No need to add the function call with an index injected this way so more elegant and to me a bit less required.  I would if I were the OP change the paragraph (`<p`) to just use a "wrapper" class instead so that would be the "`.closest(".frame-wrapper")` or some such. That way if the markup changes to say a `div` no need to change the code.

Comment: Ref link for the fullscreen: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#allowfullscreen

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Updated as suggested